# Byte-Serving Implementation - HEAD verb

Tags: http, web, http-headers

How would/should the various meta response headers (Content-MD5, Content-Length, ...) behave in regards to byte serving on an HTTP `HEAD` request?

W3 describes the HEAD verb as follows :

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself.

Therefore if I were to send the following request on a byte-serving enabled server :

```
HEAD /test.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Range: Bytes=1
Connection: close
```

... I would expect the byte serving to be applied on the implied `GET` request and an appropriate `HEAD` response would be generated with a `Content-Length : 1`.

My question is : How does/should a server respond to a request like the one above?

Comment: You're looking at an outdated spec. What's relevant are RFCs 7230...7234.

Comment: @JulianReschke Thank you, but my question still remains though.